# How to fix version problems when installing Angular with NPM?

Tags: angular, webpack-dev-server

After install I am getting this error.

`npm -v`

- 6.5.0

`node -v`

- v9.10.1

`Angular CLI`

- 7.1.4

[image]

Comment: Try to run "npm audit fix"

Comment: The required version of angular will be mentioned in the package.json which is compatible with all of the required dependencies. Once installed the npm run the `npm install` in the project folder and all of the dependencies mentioned in the package.json will be installed.

Answer (score 1):

try to reinstall your npm and and check it should work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by a typo with regards to the version number of webpack-dev-server. This has been fixed by the webpack-dev-server team, but the angular team is working on releasing an updated version of the @angular-devkit/build-angular, which includes a reference to webpack-dev-server.

The fix may be released on Wednesday January 9, 2019, according to this post:

[Link to GitHub fix](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/13347)